# XMLHTTP request error. Eclipse project with tomee7 server.

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, tomee-7

I have a tomcat tomee7 server set up in eclipse. The server is running with some serverside-code and everything works. But, when i run my client side code and try to do a request i get following error "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file://***** Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https."

What to do?

Answer (score 1):

The error suggests that your javascript code is assuming a base url of 'file://'
Are you running your client side code by just opening an html file in a browser?

Comment: Yes i do. I have it as a separate project in Eclipse. Should i run it on server aswell? in that case, how do i do that?

Comment: As far as I can see TomEE7 is an embedded enterprise application server, I don't think you want to serve html content with it. If you just want to test your server side code and you don't want complicate your work bench put a base tag (e.g. `<base href="http://localhost:8080/">`) in the <head> of your html file and you can get away with it for a while...